# Is the HTTP SEARCH method standardized?

Tags: http, search, specifications

I am thinking about how to implement a REST API endpoint for searching. As I see it, I have four options for how to implement search options, each with pros and cons:

1. Use a GET endpoint with querystring params
2. Use a GET endpoint with a payload (for example, a JSON payload)
3. Use a POST endpoint with a payload
4. Use a SEARCH endpoint with a payload

For completeness, here are the pros and cons I am thinking of:

- GET endpoint with querystring params

  - Pro - Accurate verb, standards compliant
  - Con - Limited option structure (key/values only), and URL size limit
- GET endpoint with a payload (for example, a JSON payload)

  - Pro - Accurate verb, no size limit
  - Con - HTTP specs say GET requests do not have meaningful payloads, and some frameworks may not support it ([relevant question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/978061/1455074))
- POST endpoint with a payload

  - Pro - Standards compliant, no size limit
  - Con - Searching is idempotent, while POSTing is not. Basically, it's the wrong verb.
- SEARCH endpoint with a payload

  - Pro - Accurate verb, no size limit
  - Con - Is an obscure (non-standard?) HTTP verb

A lengthy, nuanced, and opinionated discussion could be had as to which of these is best, but that discussion is not the purpose of this question. Instead I ask: Is the SEARCH verb merely obscure and rarely used but still an official method, or is it non-standard?

I found [this draft](https://trac.tools.ietf.org/id/draft-snell-search-method-00.html) for the method, but not many more official documents about it. The draft echoed some of the points of the quadrilemma I posed above. It appears to me that the method is still merely a draft and can't be called "standard", though I am not overly familiar with how to read those documents.

Functionally, I guess my question is: Can I rely on self-touted standards compliant software to handle the SEARCH method? And if they don't handle it, can I appeal to their claim of standards compliance to force them into handling it? Boiled down even further, is it a reliable verb?

Comment: The upcoming QUERY method will solve this use case, but it will only be supported by new software

Answer (score 5, accepted):

SEARCH is defined on the IETF Standards Track in [RFC 5323](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5323). That said, it currently is only applicable to WebDAV, and few servers support it.

Comment: Gotcha. As a follow up, if it is defined in a "Standards Track", does this mean that it is essentially a draft? It is moving towards being a standard, but is not one yet? I am not familiar with what that term means.

Comment: IETF terminology can be confusing. Let's just say that it has the same status as the HTTP specs.

Answer (score 4):

Almost, but they may use QUERY instead.

> HTTP SEARCH is a new HTTP method, for safe requests that include a request body. It's still early & evolving, but it was recently adopted as an IETF draft standard, and it's going to add some great new tools for HTTP development everywhere.

from httptoolkit blog

- https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/draft-ietf-httpbis-safe-method-w-body/
- https://github.com/httpwg/http-extensions/labels/safe-method-w-body
- https://httptoolkit.com/blog/http-search-method/
- https://github.com/nestjs/nest/pull/10533 NextJS v10 support SEARCH method

Answer (score 2):

SEARCH method [draft specification](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/draft-snell-search-method/) has been replaced by the HTTP [QUERY method draft](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/draft-ietf-httpbis-safe-method-w-body/).

According to the [list of the HTTP request methods](https://webconcepts.info/concepts/http-method/) SEARCH was standardized only for the [WebDAV](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/rfc5323/).